# input mask for UITextField in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can we define an input mask like `$d,ddd.dd` for data entry in a `UITextField` for an iPhone app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-Apply currency formatting to a UITextField on a change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388448/re-apply-currency-formatting-to-a-uitextfield-on-a-change-event)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obj-C, iOS, how do I format a UITextField for currency international?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850089/obj-c-ios-how-do-i-format-a-uitextfield-for-currency-international)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use an `NSNumberFormatter` to go back and forth between a value `1234.56` and a string `@"$1,234.56"`.

Apple has a very good [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html) to walk you through setting up and using a currency formatter.

In order to integrate this with a UITextField, you will want to use the delegate method

– textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

This allows you to validate and update characters as the user types them in. For an example of how to implement this, look at this post: [Re-Apply currency formatting to a UITextField on a change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388448/re-apply-currency-formatting-to-a-uitextfield-on-a-change-event)